# Unable to convert multiple URL into png image using Webshot() Package in R

Tags: r

I am a very beginner level in R programming but i researched all the available detail related to Webshot() package. The code below works when i am running for single URL.

```
library(webshot)
webshot::webshot(url = "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/abc.html",
                 file = "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/abc.png", 
                 vwidth = 1000, vheight = 1000)
```

I am trying to screenshot multiple URL and save it as png in a folder. (Reference: https://github.com/wch/webshot/blob/9a53e9e02e3936ccb32a3b767cfae6724a04026d/R/webshot.R#L63)

```
savepath <-"C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/"      #Test Path
f <- list.files(path = savepath , pattern = ".html", recursive = TRUE)
f
# [1] "abc.html"  "def.html"     "ghi.html"    "jkl.html"    "mno.html"
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:length(f), "ImageName" = tools::file_path_sans_ext(f) 
                ,"File" = c(f), "CreateDate" = c(file.info(glue("{savepath}{f}"))$ctime)
                , "InPath" = glue("{savepath}{f}")
                , "OutPath" = glue("{savepath}{tools::file_path_sans_ext(f)}.png")
)
x
# SN ImageName     File               CreateDate                                   InPath                                 OutPath
# 1       abc abc.html       2018-10-12 11:07:11 C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/abc.html C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/abc.png
# 2       def def.html       2018-10-12 11:07:11 C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/def.html C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/def.png
# 3       ghi ghi.html       2018-10-12 11:07:11 C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/ghi.html C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/ghi.png
# 4       jkl jkl.html       2018-10-12 11:07:11 C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/jkl.html C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/jkl.png
# 5       mno mno.html       2018-10-12 11:07:11 C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/mno.html C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/mno.png
```

After saving the details into a data frame and running the webshot() code as below

```
library(webshot)
webshot::webshot(url = c(x["InPath"]),
                 file = c(x["OutPath"]), 
                 vwidth = 1000, vheight = 1000)
```

> ***Error in path.expand(path) : invalid 'path' argument***

Then i tried to add "" to the values in the Inpath and Outpath columns of the data frame

```
savepath <-"C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/"      #Test Path
    f <- list.files(path = savepath , pattern = ".html", recursive = TRUE)
    f
    # [1] "abc.html"  "def.html"     "ghi.html"    "jkl.html"    "mno.html"
    x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:length(f), "ImageName" = tools::file_path_sans_ext(f) 
                    ,"File" = c(f), "CreateDate" = c(file.info(glue("{savepath}{f}"))$ctime)
            , "InPath" = glue("\"{savepath}{f}\"")
            , "OutPath" = glue("\"{savepath}{tools::file_path_sans_ext(f)}.png\""){tools::file_path_sans_ext(f)}.png")
    )
    x
    # SN ImageName     File               CreateDate                                   InPath                                 OutPath
    # 1       abc abc.html       2018-10-12 11:07:11 "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/abc.html" "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/abc.png"
    # 2       def def.html       2018-10-12 11:07:11 "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/def.html" "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/def.png"
    # 3       ghi ghi.html       2018-10-12 11:07:11 "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/ghi.html" "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/ghi.png"
    # 4       jkl jkl.html       2018-10-12 11:07:11 "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/jkl.html" "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/jkl.png"
    # 5       mno mno.html       2018-10-12 11:07:11 "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/mno.html" "C:/Users/bazinga/Documents/test/mno.png"

library(webshot)
webshot::webshot(url = c(x["InPath"]),
                 file = c(x["OutPath"]), 
                 vwidth = 1000, vheight = 1000)
```

> ***Error in vapply(url, fix_one, character(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE) :    values must be length 1,  but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 5***

I know i can call webshot() multiple times and get the results but please let me know if what i am trying to do is even possible with webshot() or not and if you have any suggestion or point me to the right approach to work this out in only calling one command.

Comment: what if you use `x[["InPath"]]` and `x[["OutPath"]]` ?

Comment: Error:

Error in vapply(url, fix_one, character(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE) : 
  values must be type 'character',
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is type 'integer'

Comment: we don't have your actual data frame (you should really use `dput()` as the R question help/FAQ says) so there's no way folks can help you further til we have the actual data you're using. Fundamentally, you aren't passing character vectors to webshot as the manual page says is required.